# Runlevels behaviour when kill script has failed

Tags: centos, init.d, runlevel, rc

When I execute `sudo init 3`, the system executes the kill scripts in /etc/rc.3/

One of those scripts returns a failure (this is expected because the thing it's trying to do won't work). When I then do a `sudo init 4`, I notice that the script that had failed doesn't get launched. Is that the default behaviour in linux?

(I'm using CentOS 5.2 final)

Comment: Is there an instance of the script in `/etc/rc.4`?

Comment: Yes, if I tailor the kill script to always return 'success', the script in `/etc/rc.4` runs successfully

Comment: CentOS 5.2 hasn't been in support since ~2009.  Perhaps you should consider running an update?